# Cumulative Mean Function Issue with Grouping Sizes

Tags: r

I have an issue with a function I have that calculates the cumulative mean with a lag of one over groups on a field:

```
cumroll <- function(x) {  x <- head(x, -1)
c(head(x,1), cumsum(x) / seq_along(x))}
```

Everything works fine as long as I am performing this function over groups that are larger than one:

```
Player <- c('B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','E','E','E','E','E')
Team <- c('B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','E','E','E','E','E')
Score <- c(2,7,3,9,6,3,7,1,7,3,8,3,4,1)
data.frame(Player, Team, Score)

test <- ave(Score, Player, Team, FUN = cumroll)
data.frame(Player, Team, Score, test)
```

However when my dataset has a grouping of size one:

```
Player <- c('A','B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','E','E','E','E','E')
Team <- c('A','B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','E','E','E','E','E')
Score <- c(5,2,7,3,9,6,3,7,1,7,3,8,3,4,1)
data.frame(Player, Team, Score)

test <- ave(Score, Player, Team, FUN = cumroll)
data.frame(Player, Team, Score, test)
```

I get the error:

```
Error in `split<-.default`(`*tmp*`, g, value = lapply(split(x, g), FUN)) : 
replacement has length zero
```

I know there is a way to modify the function to account for this. I want to give the observed value when group size is 1 in these cases. Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to change the function's behavior conditional on the length of the input is, happily, to condition on the length of the input. E.g., you can use

```
cumroll <- function(x) {
    if(length(x)<=1) {
        x 
    } else { 
        x <- head(x, -1)
        c(head(x,1), cumsum(x) / seq_along(x))
    }
}

Player <- c('A','B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','E','E','E','E','E')
Team <- c('A','B','B','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','E','E','E','E','E')
Score <- c(5,2,7,3,9,6,3,7,1,7,3,8,3,4,1)

test <- ave(Score, Player, Team, FUN = cumroll)

> data.frame(Player, Team, Score, test)
   Player Team Score     test
1       A    A     5 5.000000
2       B    B     2 2.000000
3       B    B     7 2.000000
4       C    C     3 3.000000
5       C    C     9 3.000000
6       C    C     6 6.000000
7       D    D     3 3.000000
8       D    D     7 3.000000
9       D    D     1 5.000000
10      D    D     7 3.666667
11      E    E     3 3.000000
12      E    E     8 3.000000
13      E    E     3 5.500000
14      E    E     4 4.666667
15      E    E     1 4.500000
```

But I'm a little wary about your approach...how is cumulative mean with a lag of one defined precisely? You might look at `shift` in `data.table` and `rollapply` in `zoo` to get better performance and robustness.

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff - i assume so one can see the result more clearly

Comment: @thelatemail - I just don't see the function being used.  I think there's a line missing

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff - right you are, I was just mentally filling in the blanks :-)

Comment: I have a similar question on exponential smoothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36511942/exponential-smoothing-function-issue-with-grouping-sizes

Comment: The same strategy will work in that case, and I would again encourage you to look into using pre-written tools to do your smoothing, as doing so will make it easier for you not to have to reinvent the wheel. Each of these is an example of "apply a function on a rolling window" and "compute a lag on a series," so learning to express the solution in terms of some generic functions (e.g. `rollapply`, `shift`, but possibly others) will save you time the next time you want to try a new type of lagged smoothing. Best